# Different Listview divider after last item but before footer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I set my custom divider by removing in `my_list.xml` default divider from Listview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/app_background">

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and adding `View` under every item in `my_item.xml` (`RelativeLayout` holds item icon; `LinearLayout` holds item text):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/staticmap" >
        </ImageView>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">

        ...

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#E4E4E4"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks to that I have custor divider (View) under every item text but not under item icon.

**After last item on list I want divider to be visible also under icon like so:**

[image: what I want to have]

Here are layouts inflations:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
            R.layout.my_item, R.id.label, DummyContent.ITEMS));
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list, null);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getListView().addFooterView(getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState).inflate(R.layout.my_footer, null));
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: can you post the layout you are inflating in listview adapter

Answer (score 0):

Just add the same divider view under the icon as well.

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#E4E4E4"/>
```

and make it visible in the `getView()` by checking if it is the last item in the `ListView`

Or

Just add that full width divider view to the footer and hide the current divider view in the last item, using the same `getView()`